# Validation not working on Class that extends ActiveModel::Naming, include ActiveModel::Validations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, activemodel

I and new to ruby and rails; I have the below ruby class definition that I am using in my rails 3 app.  This class is simply used as a property container for contact information populated in my view on submit (form_for).  I read a post where you can use ActiveModel directly apart from ActiveRecord, to perform validation, so I am trying it.  I am getting the following exception when I check to see if the the object is valid? in my controller on postback.  I assumed that valid? would be available being that I included ActiveModel::Validations; perhaps I am doing a few other things a$$ backwards.  Any help would be appreciated:

undefined method `valid?' for #

Here's my class definition, further down is how I am handling it in my controller action:

```
require 'active_model'

class ContactModel
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::AttributeMethods
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion

  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :email_address, :email_address_confirmed, :subject, :contact_message

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :email_address, :email_address_confirmed,
                :telephone_number, :subject, :contact_message
```

## Just messing around testing.

```
  validates_each :first_name, :last_name do |record, attr, value|
    record.errors.add attr, 'starts with z.' if value.to_s[0] == z
  end
...
end
```

In my controller/action...

```
def send_email
    #@contact_model = ContactModel.new().initialize_copy(params[:contact_model])
    @contact_model = params[:contact_model].dup

    respond_to do |format|
      if (@contact_model.valid?)
        # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome Email after save
        ContactMailer.contact_email(@contact_model).deliver

        format.html { redirect_to(@contact_model, notice: 'Email successfully sent.') }
        format.json { render json: @contact_model, status: :created, location: @contact_model }
      else
        # What to do here?
      end

    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you are setting `@contact_model` to a hash, `params[:contact_model]`, and then calling `valid?` on it. You need create an instance of ContactModel and call valid on that.  Like so:

```
@contact_model = ContactModel.new(params[:contact_model])

if (@contact_model.valid?)
...
```

I see commented out code that calls ContactModel.new(), but that's not how you want to do it anyway.  Also, there is no reason to dup() or initialize_copy() on the params stuff.

Comment: By jove, I think you've got it. Thank you.